# sending an email with aws nodejs sdk (using the aws sdk nodejs docs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm not able to understand the AWS NodeJs SDK docs.  Specifically, I'm trying to generate sample json params for the sendmail method.  Does anyone have a sample json structure for sendmail, or does AWS have those samples available?  Thanks

[aws sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html)

edit:
I see that nodemailer wraps SES.  I will give this a try
https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the nodemailer package makes mail much easier.  Still unsure on the json structure for AWS SES

Answer (score 1):

Sending email with the [nodejs AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/) looks like that:

```
var AWS = requires('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

var SES = new AWS.SES();
var params = {
  Destination: {
    ToAddresses : 'you@gmail.com'
  },
  Source: 'me@gmail.com',
  Message: {
    Body: {
      Text: {
        Data: 'Hello world'
      }
    }, 
    Subject: {
      Data: 'Hello world'
    }
  }
};
SES.sendEmail(params, , function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

detailed documentation is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendEmail-property)